# combining two dictionary to create a new dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that maps orders to bins.

```
orders_to_bins={1: 'a', 2:'a', 3:'b'}
```

I have another dictionary that shows the items in the orders.

```
items={1:[49,50,51,62],
       2:[60,63,64,65],
       3:[70,71,72,74]}
```

I need to create a new dictionary that shows the items in the bins like this.

```
items_in_bins={'a':[49,50,51,62,60,63,64,65],
               'b':[70,71,72,74]}
```

I am looking for hints or solutions on how to achieve the last dictionary from the first two.

Comment: Others will usually be more likely to help if they have seen the OP make some attempt at a solution. You wont learn much if someone just tells you the answer.

Comment: @PaulRooney I actually tried a few ways using dictionary comprehension but did not work, would've been nice to get some more suggestions or hints from experienced people, that way other people could've learned too.

Comment: don't be afraid to post a wrong solution. It will help you to get feedback on your code as well as getting someone elses solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer uses a `defaultdict`, which is essentially a regular python dictionary where every new value is automatically initialized to be a particular type (in this case `list`).

For every (key, value)-pair in the `orders_to_bins` (extracted with the `.items()` method), we extend the `items_in_bins` list for a particular key, which is the `bin_name` from whatever is in `items`.

Here is what that looks like:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

items_in_bins = defaultdict(list)

for order, bin_name in orders_to_bins.items():
    items_in_bins[bin_name].extend(items[order])
```

```
>>> print(dict(items_in_bins))
{'a': [49, 50, 51, 62, 60, 63, 64, 65], 'b': [70, 71, 72, 74]}
```

Note, in the print statement, I am making it back to a regular `dict` for ease of reading, but that is not necessary.

Also note, if you are unsure if items will be populated, you could do `items.get(order, [])` instead of `items[order]` to ensure that it does not fail on missing keys. But, that is up to you and dependent on what you are trying to do (i.e. maybe that is a valid error).

Comment: Thanks, I have never used defaultdict before, learned something new today. The solution works.